# Confused about the result Modulo in PHP

Tags: php

Fairly new to PHP and have come across this while learning and I understand Its using a formula to turn the date into a whole number from 1-11 (and then allocate the number to the Chinese zodiac)
I don’t get how it derives a whole number from the formula given though could anyone explain would be great ?

```
<?php

$year = 2013;
    switch (($year - 4) % 12) {
        case  0: $zodiac = 'Rat';   break;
        case  1: $zodiac = 'Ox';        break;
        case  2: $zodiac = 'Tiger';     break;
        case  3: $zodiac = 'Rabbit';    break;
        case  4: $zodiac = 'Dragon';    break;
        case  5: $zodiac = 'Snake';     break;
        case  6: $zodiac = 'Horse';     break;
        case  7: $zodiac = 'Goat';      break;
        case  8: $zodiac = 'Monkey';    break;
        case  9: $zodiac = 'Rooster';   break;
        case 10: $zodiac = 'Dog';       break;
        case 11: $zodiac = 'Pig';       break;
    }
    echo "{$year} is the year of the {$zodiac}.<br />";


?>
```

The answer is 2013 is the year of the Snake.

Comment: Do you understand the modulus operator (`%`)? See [PHP arithmetic operators](http://us1.php.net/operators.arithmetic).

Comment: Modulo is the operator which gives you the remainder after integer division. If you divide 11 by 2 for example, you get 5 and remainder is 1 (2 * 5 = 10, 10 + 1 = 11). That means 11 modulo 2 is 1. If you divide 20 by 2, remainder is 0 (it divides into 10) and so on. Reading the algorithm above, what it does is `subtract 4 from $year, get the remainder after dividing by 12 and then check what value you got`.

Comment: Makes sense but why would you need to minus 4 from the year ?

Comment: Why **subtract** 4? To align with the Year of the Rat being the first house (index 0). You want to get a year which modulo 12 is 0 (provided the $year _is_ TYoTR).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is fairly simple.

the % operand gives the leftover from a division.

examples:

13 % 12 = 1

5 % 3 = 2

I hope it's clear enough.

Comment: It makes sense with the examples you have provided. But why do i need to minus 4 from the $year to then get the remainder of dividing it by 12 ? Hope that makes sense I think this is more of a maths question really.

Comment: @user1829823 minus 4 has nothing to do this. If you copied it from another site I guess it's because the original author checked it if the results of the script are correct. He could also start with the ox and leave the minus 4.

Comment: The traditional canonical order starts with Rat.

Answer (score 0):

By using a calculator

```
2013-4=2009
2009/12= 167.41666
167*12=2004
2009-2004=5 (5 is snake which was the animal for 2013)
```

Answer (score 0):

-4 might be the value to align the year to the Chinese zodiac calendar.